# Creating an Array of pointers to member functions

Tags: c++

In short, I tried searching on how to do this, but I seem to be missing something. One constraint to my problem: Human.h cannot change. We must operate with what we've been given. I am also told to create the array of pointers to members to decide on which function needs to be called.

Here's what I have:

Human.h

```
class Human
{
private:
    void meleeAttack(std::string const& target);
    void rangedAttack(std::string const& target);
    void intimidatingShout(std::string const& target);
public:
    void action(std::string const& action_name, std::string const& target);
};
```

Human.cpp

```
#include "Human.h"

typedef void (Human::* Human_mem_fnPtr)(std::string target);

void Human::meleeAttack(std::string const& target)
{
    std::cout << "Melee Attack performed on " << target << "!\n";
}

void Human::rangedAttack(std::string const& target)
{
    std::cout << "Ranged Attack performed on " << target << "!\n";
}

void Human::intimidatingShout(std::string const& target)
{
    std::cout << "Shout performed on " << target << "!\n";
}

void Human::action(std::string const& action_name, std::string const& target)
{
    //error on initialization--expression must be an lvalue or function designation--but they ARE func designations...
    Human_mem_fnPtr fnPtr[] = {&Human::meleeAttack(target), &Human::rangedAttack(target), &Human::intimidatingShout(target)}; 
}
```

From what I found online, I am going in the right direction here. What am I missing?

Comment: Those are not actual function designations... you'd want &Human::meleeAttack, etc. I believe.

Comment: Looks like a good place for a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) of `std::string`s to [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)s.

Comment: "`&Human::meleeAttack`" is a member function pointer. What, specifically, in your C++ textbook led you to believe that "`&Human::meleeAttack(target)`" is what it should be, instead?

Comment: other note: `typedef void (Human::* Human_mem_fnPtr)(std::string target);` eats a `std::string`. `void Human::meleeAttack(std::string const& target)` eats a `const` reference to a `std::string`. They gotta match.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the function requires an argument. That was my reasoning. But I can see where you wouldn't use that until calling out the index specifically. Regardless, if I take that out, I get an error on `Human_mem_fnPtr fnPtr[] = {&Human::meleeAttack...` saying a type initialization problem

Comment: @agile_flow The type requires an argument, and the function pointer has to refer to a function that has the correct signature as defined in your typedef.

Comment: "Reasoning" counts very little, when C++ is concerned. What matters is how C++ actually works, which is where a good textbook comes in. A search engine is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. There's all sorts of garbage out there, that a search engine will happily return to you, because the pile of junk includes the right keywords. Attempts to learn the most complicated and difficult programming language in use today from reading search engine results always ends in tears.

Comment: I am using Stroustrups 'C++ Programming Language'--but I needed an example that was easier to read. Thanks for the suggestion, but I still need help here. Initializing `Human_mem_fnPtr fnPtr[]` doesn't work even when I use `&Human::meleeAttack`

Comment: You don't see the difference between the actual parameter defined for each member function, a "`std::string const&`", and your `Human_mem_fnPtr` claiming that it should be a `std::string`, instead? Everything must be 100% correct, and match, in C++, "close enough" is never enough. I'm also curious to learn which chapter in Stroustrups offers creating a role-playing D&D kind of a game, as a practice coding task, like the shown code seems to suggest.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I got it now. I had the const right, I was just missing a reference character. Dude, you gotta just give an answer without the condescending nature of your reply. Would have been easy rep for you but instead you chose to be rude.

Comment: Side note: Sometimes you'll see people using casts to make a function fit in a function pointer. These people are either wasting their time with the cast or shooting themselves in the face. When Sam says the parameters need to match exactly, he's not kidding. The folks playing with the cast are likely getting unlucky and not seeing the problem because the program looks like it works. And it'll keep working until the worst possible time, like when the boss is on stage at a tradeshow demoing your work.

Comment: Side note: [Really good reading on thew care and feeding of function pointers](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members).

Comment: Well, I'm not really desperate for karma right now, but what precisely gave you a "condescending" impression, can you be specific? I'm always happy to get constructive feedback. Is it condescending to point out that C++ demands everything to match, 100%, correctly? No, that's absolutely true, and it is not condescending to state that. And it was certainly true that, somehow, you missed the difference between a plain `string`, and a long-winded `std::string const &`. Everyone makes mistake, that's ok, and it's not condescending to point out some obvious observations.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik telling me that 'Reasoning' counts very little-- you don't need to belittle me here. I have a textbook and a good one--you assumed I am trying to learn the language by googling. And I never said the example problem came from his book--you are just providing opinionated filler here that isn't actually answering the question. Yes you got to it, but with comments that make people not feel welcome here. You could have simply posted an answer with the like: `It looks like your typedef declaration and variable initialization don't match argument wise. Here's what it should be...`

Comment: This was not meant to belittle you. That's just to point out that when it comes to C++, one's own wits are rarely enough to figure things out. Even I don't try to figure out what I don't know already: I look it up. After C++'s first major update, in 2011, I got the requisite reference material, and read it. I didn't try to "reason" anything. And I assumed nothing, I went by what you wrote: "from what I found online".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points:

- Doing pointers to functions is made much easier with the `std::function<>` template class.
- Using a old-style array is not really the best choice these days.

A `map` or `unordered_map` would be a much better option, with a definition like this:

```
using ActionMap = std::unordered_map<const std::string, std::function<void(const std::string&)>;
```

When adding your functions to this map you would use something like the following:

```
mActionMap["rangedAttack"] =  std::mem_fn(&Human::rangedAttack);
```

This will give you a cleaner and easier to maintain option and should compile cleanly.

Note that the `std::mem_fn` is required to wrap a member function of a class.

Edit: Per your comment below, Id still suggest using as many of the modern C++ constructs as possible.

`using ActionFunc = std::function<void(const std::string&)>;`

And then:

`ActionFunc actions[] = { std::mem_fn(&Human::rangedAttack), ...}`

or:

`std::array<ActionFunc> actions = ...`

Comment: I appreciate the answer here--but this does not follow the constraints to the problem:

>  I am also told to create the array of pointers to members to decide on which function needs to be called.

Comment: @agile_flow Hmmm... an array could still be a `std::array` instead of the naked kind. Mapping an array index to a string will still require some kind of relational table... and I'd still recommend using `std::function` to create your function signature and create an array of those (with `using` instead of `typedef`) and insert with the `std::mem_fn' call.

Comment: Example of above: https://godbolt.org/z/eTc5neWM5 Even if you can't use the `map` the rest should be helpful. Without the `map` the assignment is "Stupid". You'll need an `if` or `switch` to convert the `action_name`s into array indexes and at that point you might as well just call the <expletive deleted>ing methods directly.

Comment: [Or I'm overthinking.](https://godbolt.org/z/Yh8r1W18o) There's an only slightly idiotic `map` of `string` to array index and array of method pointers. The kicker is the more stuff you have to change, the more likely you are to screw up. say you add a "spell" action. You have to add an item to the array and to the map, and the map sure as <expletive deleted> better match the array. By making students work harder on their assignments, teachers are actually making worse programmers a lot of the time. Laziness is a virtue.

Comment: Ha yes, that is the other kicker (I didn't mention). Multiple ifs/switches are not allowed. I understand the assignment isn't leading me to best practices at the moment--it is rather trying to teach about certain language aspects and solve the problem in front of me with a selection of tools.

Comment: A combination of this answer + comments have been helpful. I appreciate y'alls feedback on my journey to improving. Thank you!

Comment: No `if` ghettos suggests maybe a manual mapping is in order. Rather than `Human_mem_fnPtr fnPtr[]`, consider `struct action_mapper {std::string name, Human_mem_fnPtr action; }; and `action_mapper actions[] = { {"melee",&Human::meleeAttack}, ... };` Iterate that with a `for` loop until it hits the end or  `name` matches `action_name`. The goal is to keep the key and value in the same package so it's harder to get things mixed up.

Comment: In the case where the list of possibilities is really short the O(n) `for` loop is so stupid and so simple that it's probably faster than the map with its O(lon(n)) smarts and extra overhead needed to support the extra smarts. Computers are really good at being stupid really fast, so often it takes a surprisingly long list to for the inertia of stupidity to be outmatched.

Comment: [Really stupid example](https://godbolt.org/z/Md545heTj). Also an example of the compiler crapping out a bogus warning. And with the mapping `struct`: https://godbolt.org/z/vac87W3s9 Way easier.